# Table creation failed: (1064) You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql

What's wrong with my code?

```
$query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'data_table' (
    'id' INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    'name' VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    'active' TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    'create_date' TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    'income' INT DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ('id')
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;";

$createTable = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
```

Comment: You use [backticks or double quotes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html), not single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

you do not need single quotes for the table and column names try without that:you can use `" or backticks` instead.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data_table(
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
name VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
active TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT  '1',
create_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
income INT DEFAULT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( id )
) ENGINE = MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT =1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data_table` (
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `active` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    `create_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `income` INT DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;";
```

Note that the single quote is replaced with the backtick